# An example to show that direct product is not necessarily cancellative for infinite groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I'm looking for an example of $A,B,C$ such that $A\times B \cong C\times B$ but $A,C$ are not isomorphic.

I've tried many infinite groups but none get to the answer,any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why is the question closed,I can't see any unclear point in it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let  $A={\mathbb Z}_2$, $C =  {\mathbb Z}_2\times {\mathbb Z}_2$ and $B={\mathbb Z}_2\times{\mathbb Z}_2 \times {\mathbb Z}_2\times \dots $.

Comment: For OP: this generalizes extremely easily to any group.

Comment: The example also shows that $A$ and $C$ do not have to be isomorphic: if you see $A \times B \cong C \times B$ then you are inclined to say, hey divide out at both sides by $\{1\} \times B$, so $A$ and $C$ must be isomorphic. Unfortunately, not true!

Comment: Is $B$ infinite direct product of ${\mathbb Z}_2 $?How is this a group?,and sorry I ment $A,C$ are not isomorphic ,just edited.

Comment: Now I am puzzled. An infinite direct product? Of course this is a group! And @Cameron Williams: "to any *finite* group".

Comment: Sorry if I asked an prime question,I just learnt about the topic.and Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: No problem, you learned something here, right? Do not hesitate to post your future question. The dumbest question is the question not asked.